# How could I possibly create two of the same thing in java

Tags: java, object, builder, city

Okay, so my question is, in swing, how could i make two of the same thing while they both have the same attributes but yet can act independently, for example, i am working on a city builder, when the uses presses a button to add a oil power station, the power station will get added to the world, however, there is only one. how could i make it so that the player could make a seamless amount of the same building but yet they all act independently, e.g when i go to add a second of the same building the first one won't follow the mouse.
heres my current code to help explain my issue:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Game extends JFrame{



public Image map;
public Image utilButton;
public Image resButton;
public Image oilPlantBox;
public Image apartmentBlockABox;

//Building Img
public Image oilPowerStation;
public Image apartmentBlockA;

//Util selects
boolean showUtil = false;
boolean UtilSelect = false;

//Residential selects
boolean showRes = false;
boolean resSelect = false;

//Oil Power Station
boolean showOPPBox = true;
boolean checkOilPowerPlant = false;
boolean drawOilPlant = false;
boolean setPowerStation = false;
boolean placeOilPowerPlant = true;
int OilPowerStationxX = 0;
int OilPowerStationY = 0;

//Apartment Block A
boolean showABA = true;
boolean checkApartmentBlockA = false;
boolean drawApartmentBlockA = false;
boolean setApartmentBlockA = false;
boolean placeApartmentBlockA = true;
int apartmentBlockAX = 0;
int apartmentBlockAY = 0;



int x;
int y;


public int power = 0;
int jobs = 0;


public Game(){

    //Load Images:
    ImageIcon mapI = new ImageIcon("C:/Programs/Eclipse/eclipse/CityCenterBeta/bin/map.jpg");
    map = mapI.getImage();
    ImageIcon utilButtonI = new ImageIcon("C:/Programs/Eclipse/eclipse/CityCenterBeta/bin/UTIL.jpg");
    utilButton = utilButtonI.getImage();
    ImageIcon resButtonI = new ImageIcon("C:/Programs/Eclipse/eclipse/CityCenterBeta/bin/RES.jpg");
    resButton = resButtonI.getImage();
    ImageIcon oPB = new ImageIcon("C:/Programs/Eclipse/eclipse/CityCenterBeta/bin/oilPlantBox.png");
    oilPlantBox = oPB.getImage();
    ImageIcon aBAB = new ImageIcon("C:/Programs/Eclipse/eclipse/CityCenterBeta/bin/apartmentABlock.jpg");
    apartmentBlockABox = aBAB.getImage();

    //Building Images

    //Oil Power Station
    ImageIcon oilPlantI = new ImageIcon("C:/Programs/Eclipse/eclipse/CityCenterBeta/bin/oilPlant.jpg");
    oilPowerStation = oilPlantI.getImage();

    //Apartment Block A
    ImageIcon apartmentBlockI = new ImageIcon("C:/Programs/Eclipse/eclipse/CityCenterBeta/bin/apartment block.jpg");
    apartmentBlockA = apartmentBlockI.getImage();



    //Set up game
      addKeyListener(new AL());
       addMouseListener(new Mouse());
       init();




}


private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;


public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Game();
}



//When the program runs, thins are initialised here
public void init(){

    windowManager();
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    g.drawImage(map,0,0,null);
    g.drawImage(utilButton,20,100,null);
    g.drawImage(resButton,20,200,null);


    if(showUtil == true){
        if(showOPPBox == true){
        g.drawImage(oilPlantBox,190,130,null);
        }
    }
    if(showRes == true){
        if(showABA == true){
            g.drawImage(apartmentBlockABox,190,130,null);
        }
    }

    if(drawOilPlant == true){
        g.drawImage(oilPowerStation,OilPowerStationxX,OilPowerStationY,null);
        if(checkOilPowerPlant == true){
        setPowerStation = true;
        }

    if(drawApartmentBlockA == true){
        g.drawImage(apartmentBlockA,apartmentBlockAX,apartmentBlockAY,null);
        if(checkApartmentBlockA == true){
            setApartmentBlockA = true;
        }
    }
    }





    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage,0,0,this);




}

public void windowManager(){

      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      setTitle("City Center");
      setVisible(true);
      setResizable(false);
      setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setExtendedState(f.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      setUndecorated(true);


}


public class AL extends KeyAdapter{

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == e.VK_ENTER){
            if(setPowerStation == true)
                placeOilPowerPlant = false;
                checkOilPowerPlant = false;
                setPowerStation = false;         
                showUtil = false;
                UtilSelect = false;
                showOPPBox = false;
                oilPlantAtt();
                System.out.println(jobs + " Job Openings");
                System.out.println(power + "MW");
                }
        if(setApartmentBlockA == true){
            placeApartmentBlockA = false;
            checkApartmentBlockA = false;
            setApartmentBlockA = false;
            showRes = false;
            resSelect = false;
            showABA = false;
            apartmentBlockAtt();
        }

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){


    }


}

public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter {

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
     x = e.getX();
     y = e.getY();
     //Pressed Utilies button
     if((x > 20) && (x < 120) && (y > 100) && (y < 200) && (showUtil == false))          {
            showUtil = true;
            UtilSelect = true;      
            showRes = false;
            resSelect = false;
}
     //Pressed Residential Button
     if((x > 20) && (x < 120) && (y > 200) && (y < 300) && (showRes == false)){
        showRes = true;
        resSelect = true;
        showUtil = false;
        UtilSelect = false;
     }

     if((x > 190) && (x < 265) && (y > 130) && (y < 192)){
         if(resSelect == true){
             drawApartmentBlockA = true;
             if(placeApartmentBlockA == true){
                 checkApartmentBlockA = true;
             }
         }
         if(UtilSelect == true){
             drawOilPlant = true;
                if(placeOilPoerPlant == true){
                checkOilPowerPlant = true; 
         }


     }
    }
    if(setPowerStation == true){
        OilPowerStationxX = x;
        OilPowerStationY = y;
    }else{
        OilPowerStationxX = OilPowerStationxX;
        OilPowerStationY = OilPowerStationY;
    }
    if(setApartmentBlockA == true){
        apartmentBlockAX = x;
        apartmentBlockAY = y;
    }else{
        apartmentBlockAX = apartmentBlockAX;
        apartmentBlockAY = apartmentBlockAY;
    }
 }



 }












public void oilPlantAtt(){

jobs = jobs + 150;
power = power + 1000;
}
public void apartmentBlockAtt(){
boolean work = false;
if(power > 0){
    work = true;
}
if(work == true){
jobs = jobs - 300;
power = power - 100;
}
 }
```

Comment: Clone it and thats a clone.

Comment: Object.clone() , is it what u are asking for ? Implement your class to be Clonable , and Do the method implementation to copy as u want and Here u go

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to create 2 different instances with the similar properties or try this snippet:

```
Object building = new Object();
building.isLockedInPlace = false;
```

And use `building.isLockedInPlace` to say if you have one down.
To have multiple, you will have to use `Object.clone();`.

Hope it works and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your problem description and your provided code, it appears that you are new to [object-oriented programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), which Java revolves around. If you haven't done so already, I'd recommend looking through [the core Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) again, regarding objects and their use.

As it stands, you have included everything in one file: the attributes of your power plant, of your apartment block, etc. What your program should look like is the following:

- A Game class (which you have already) that contains either one or a collection of City objects.
- A City class which contains a collection of Building objects.
- A Building class could be abstract or an interface, which your ApartmentBlock and PowerPlant classes would extend or implement.

This structure is extensible and allows you to easily add more buildings and building types. You can also better enforce [data encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) (which you aren't doing at all here), as each concrete building class (like your ApartmentBlock and PowerPlant) would also be the only ones who cared about what image they were displaying, and other data building specific information that only they really need to know.